# New "OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed" error when getting an access code for an Office 365 resource

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365api

We have the following steps to authenticate with Office 365 and get the access tokens required to request calendar events...

1. Send the user to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code , passing the client id and a redirect URL
2. The user logs in and is redirected back to the redirect URL with a ?code= query string value
3. Make an API request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token to get a token for the https://api.office.com/discovery/ resource, passing the code that we got in step 2
4. Store the access token and refresh token which is returned
5. Make an API request to https://api.office.com/discovery/v2.0/me/services to get a list of end points that we have access to
6. For the end point that I want to work with (Office 365 Exchange) , make an API request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token to get a token for the https://outlook.office365.com/ resource, passing the code that we got in step 2
7. Store the access token and refresh token which is returned
8. Use the access token from step 7 to fetch calendar events

This used to work fine, but today I'm getting a different result from the API call on step 6

I used to get an access token and refresh token which I could use for the outlook.office365.com resource, but now I'm getting an error message like the following...

```
{
    "error":"invalid_grant",
    "error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token.
    Trace ID: 37f11c2c-6450-4040-b297-48268c6d4b00
    Correlation ID: afdeb0cb-c14a-4267-9a5d-2422a1f84d62
    Timestamp: 2019-01-29 22:26:24Z",
    "error_codes":[70002,54005],
    "timestamp":"2019-01-29 22:26:24Z",
    "trace_id":"37f11c2c-6450-4040-b297-48268c6d4b00",
    "correlation_id":"afdeb0cb-c14a-4267-9a5d-2422a1f84d62"
}
```

So it looks like I need to pass a different code the second time I make a request to get access tokens, but where do I get this different code from?

Comment: You cannot reuse the code.  To refresh a token, you call the endpoint for refresh and pass the refresh token. The refresh token is used to get a new access token and optionally the id token.

Comment: Thanks John - the trouble is that I need to get an access token for the https://api.office.com/discovery/ resource, and then get a different access token for the https://outlook.office365.com/ resource. So I need to make two calls to the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token API, each requiring me to pass a code. But it's only letting use that code once

Comment: You cannot use the OAuth 2.0 `code` more than once. Make two independant calls to the authorize endpoint. The fact that this worked before means that the OAuth 2.0 spec was not followed. Someone fixed that.

Comment: Hi John, thanks a lot for your answers - I've just tested sending the user to the authorise page a second time to get a second code, and it's working great

Comment: I have the same problem, which endpoint to update to receive the new update token?